# Merging and snapping shapefiles

Tags: qgis, shapefile, merge, snapping, large-datasets

I have several large shapefiles from various sources. All cover various sections of oceans and many overlaps, as such the coastline is repeated across the several shapefiles but to varying levels of details/accuracy.

The outcome I would like to achieve is one shapefile, with one coastline.

I can merge the shapefiles in QGIS but how would I align the coastline and drop its duplication?

Comment: Maybe it can be done with _Differences_ and _Unions_. Also, you can try the _snap_ tool of GRASS _v.clean_ algorithm. The solution to your problem will be more or less handmade and specific according to your source data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Menu Processing / Toolbox / Merge vector layers` and set all the layers you want to merge. See the result:

[image]

Now you can dissolve the output layer: `Menu Vector / Geoprocessing Tools / Dissolve` and you get the maximal extenstion of all features in the output, see:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, looks like it should do the trick but i'll get back to you once QGIS is done processing. Thanks again